# Magento 2 installation error – Allowed memory size

Tags: magento2, installation

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 32768 bytes) in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog-graph-ql\Model\Resolver\Product\Price.php
>   on line 1

Comment: what is your memory size in php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to fix this is to increase your server memory limit you can do this by using one of the following methods

Inside app/bootstrap.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

In your php.ini file (if unsure of the location run **php --ini**)

```
memory_limit=1024M
```

This should resolve the issue i would recommend the php.ini solution over the ini_set option.

Answer (score 1):

Increase PHP Memory Limit in your php.ini file:

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

If you don't know your php.ini location, it is probably located at: `C:\xampp1\php\php.ini` or you can run `phpinfo()` and you'll see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please install magento2 via command line, try with below command :

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="admin" --key="admin" --session-save="files" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento_2_db" --db-user="root" --db-password="root" --base-url="http://local.magento.com/" --base-url-secure="https://local.magento2.com/" --admin-user="adams" --admin-password="admin123" --admin-email="adams@example.com" --admin-firstname="adams" --admin-lastname="ronaldo"
```